# WPF: calendar as a comboboxitem sets selected value as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, calendar

I am trying to implement a ComboBox with a calendar as its item. When the user selects a date on the calendar, this date becomes the ComboBox value/text. problem is when I click outside the ComboBox to close or the ComboBox goes unselected, the value then becomes "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem".

**How do I keep the ComboBox value to the ShortDate string value even after the ComboBox loses focus?**

here's my xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="datecombo" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDates}">
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <controls:Calendar x:Name="DropCalendar" SelectedDatesChanged="DropCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged CalendarSelectionMode="SingleRange"/>
                    </ComboBoxItem></ComboBox>
```

In the code behind I have a viewmodel that contains the property SelectedDates (bound to the selectedvalue attribute) which is set when the selected dates on the calendar change. This in turn sets the ComboBox value to the short date string  of the selected date.

**edit: I think I need to use a Calendar because I want to be able to select a range of dates. I know this can also be possible to do with two DatePickers(one is for the start and the other for the end date) but I think doing this(Calendar on a ComboBox) would better fit with the UI's aesthetic, i guess. :D

Comment: Do you have to use a ComboBox? This sound slike a better fit for a DatePicker - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PhilipCampbell yup, because i need to be able to select a range of dates which is not available in datepickers(i think)